# Delete button disappeared on scrolling in edit mode of UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing the issue when I scroll the tableview in edit mode. It's because of reusability of cells. I followed the link-
[UITableView in Edit Mode - Delete Button Dissapears on Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877517/uitableview-in-edit-mode-delete-button-dissapears-on-scroll)

Got nothing from that.

Here is my code snippet-

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
      animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
   [tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
   [tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:editing];

}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return NO;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

   if (cell == nil)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    }

 [cell setEditingAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];

 cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row+1];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"";


 cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
 return cell;
}
```

[image: Delete button behavior on scrolling]

So any recommendation or suggestion from anyone how to resolve that issue?

Thank you.

Comment: From where you take the reference that OP also facing the same issue and there is no solution is available for the same issue.

Comment: @agent_stack OP?
I am looking for the same. Let see if anyone has solved that issue.

Comment: OP means the **original poster**  means who started the discussion thread like here you are the OP.

Comment: Try declaring tableview property with strong attribute... I faced this kind of issue but not the exact when I change the tableview property with strong instead of weak it works fine

Comment: @agent_stack Okay. I googled it and found that link which had the same issue.

Comment: which version of xCode you are using?

Comment: Have you set _tablview.editing = true; ? B'Coz  i have just copy your code and it's all working in my project.

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya xCode version 8.2.1. Yes I have set that in my setEditing method. Find in my post.

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya which xCode you are using?
And where have you changed the code any if?

Comment: @Sivagami Not working in my case though I have changed the property to strong to weak and vise versa.

Comment: my xcode  xCode version 8.2.1. is same and i am used storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139208/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-jignesh-vadadoriya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated` method into this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    _myTV.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing) {
        [_myTV setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    } else {
        [_myTV setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: you save my day. Beauty.

Conclusion:

_myTV.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO; // For single selection.
and _myTV.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing; //For multi selection.

Comment: yeah sure. Done it :)

Comment: @Amir Khan Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return YES; // return yes
}
```

Now run your program and let me know what happening?

> edit

Get this demo from [here](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options). Nice exlanation is given

Comment: Delete button removed and showing empty circle now.

Comment: @AmirKhan check this sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left-objective-c-or-swift

Comment: @AmirKhan get the demo as I shared in my answer.